# How do you automatically send an email on Google form submit, from the person who submitted the form and not the Google form owner?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, triggers, google-forms

After someone (authorised and not myself) submits the Google form I created, which sends an email out to whoever they want, it shows that I (the Google form owner) sent it out myself. Is there a way to remove my email and show the email of the person who submitted the form?

This is the code in Apps Script

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 let responses = e.namedValues;

 MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: responses['Email'],
  subject: responses['Subject'],
  htmlBody: responses['Message'],
 });
}
```

I believe it might involve using Google Cloud Projects and an API, but I have little/no experience with those.

Comment: You need to know which service the user is using for mail. For Gmail, you must use Google OAuth and authenticate the user. Then connect to Gmail to send an email using the user's credentials (OAuth token). If they are using a different mail service, you cannot with Google OAuth. For example, Office 365 has its own authorization system. Your task is not a simple one and has many challenges. There are many email systems.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hey John thanks for the advice! I can confirm that all the users will be using Gmail (Not 100% sure if all the receivers will be Gmail. Please let me know if that would matter). If all users are part of the same organisation, would I still need to  authenticate each user or am I able to authenticate everyone under the org?

Comment: The recipients do not matter, just the sender. If the users are part of Google Workspace then you can use Domain Wide Delegation to impersonate each user. Edit your question so that you are providing all details instead of Q&A comments. https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#optional_set_up_domain-wide_delegation_for_a_service_account Also search StackOverflow as there are a few Q&A on delegation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because your script is using an installable trigger and the Google Apps Script Mail service, as the script is ran using the credentials of the user who create the trigger, in this case you.

In order to send an email using the form submitter email address as sender, one option is to use

1. Google Workspace accounts from the same domain
2. Service account
3. Domain wide delegation of authority

There might be other options to send the emails as the form submitter but all that have thinking about using Google Forms looks to be cumberstone.

A more simple option, still using Google Apps Script, is to create a web app and set it as run as the user accesing the web app.

The more simple solution to avoid showing your email address as the sender is to change the approach: use an alias with a generic name. To do this add an alias to your Gmail account, use GmailApp instead of MailApp and set the script to use the alias instead of your email address.